# Handling irregular temporal observations of dependent variable in panel data

Tags: logistic, panel-data, binary-data, fixed-effects-model

Dear statisticians and enthousiasts,

I'm writing my master's thesis and am dealing with an issue trying to assess the effect of my continuous predictor variables on my partially 'missing' dependent variable. A summary of the problem: My panel data matrix consists of predictor and control variables with annual observations for 2002-2022. But my dependent variable, voting results, is only observed three times within this period (in 2008, 2014, and 2022). Consequently, 18 out of 21 observations for my dependent variable are considered missing by R, creating a bit of a sparse matrix that ruins my regression.

I am using a simple fixed effects binary logistic regression in R:

```
library(bife) 
library(openxlsx)

data <- read.xlsx("dataset")

data$sum.dem.aid <- data$sum.EC.dem.aid + data$sum.US.dem.aid + data$sum.MS.dem.aid

model_bife <- bife(votes ~ sum.dem.aid + GDP + GSoDI.average +                 
          sum.total.dev.aid + perc.china.export + perc.russia.export +
          perc.US.export + perc.EU.export | ISO3,data = data)
```

Does anyone have experience with this problem and know what's the most scientifically valid or standard way to deal with it?

*Some more context if needed:
I am researching the effects of democracy aid on UN General Assembly voting results regarding resolutions condemning Russian invasions (Abkhazia, Georgia in 2008, Crimea, Ukraine in 2014, and the whole of Ukraine in 2022). So the dataset contains the amount of democracy aid received by every UN member per year as a predictor variable, and includes control variables such as GDP, development aid, democracy scores, and import and export to superpowers. My tutor is not an expert in quantitative methods and so is of little help.*